# Is there an Atom plugin to add comment headers that are visible in a minimap?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm looking for a plugin that lets adding comment headers that are visible in minimaps, as illustrated in this image:

[image]

You can see the "TABS", "TREEVIEW", "CURSOR", etc. headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following package: https://atom.io/packages/figlet

It will allow you to convert the selected text into ASCII art using [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/), allowing you to specify which font to use.

Then you just need to add the required comment characters at the beginning of each line.

[image]